# Can I add a watermark to Cognos report only for the PDF format?

Tags: watermark, cognos-8

I know I can add background for report page,then there is a watermark for both html format and pdf format,but I don't want this image show in html format,just show in pdf. How can I do this? I am using cognos8.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using conditional formating ...You can create a prompt page to select PDF or HTML output in a dropdown then accordingly use conditional formating to hide/unhide the background watermark

Comment: Thanks,will try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you skip the prompt and use the ReportOutput() function in a variable to control what renders in what output format.

Comment: I think this is what I want exactly, can you give the detail  description? I didn't have such experience before.

Comment: Create a boolean variable. Expression is ReportOutput() = 'PDF'. Create the watermark object. Assign the variable to the "Render Variable" property of the object to render on true. If you want a classic watermark which overlays the result data, you'll have to accomplish it via custom SQL and an absolute positioned object.